# Misplaced bracket? What is wrong with my code?

Tags: php

In the code below, I think I messed up this part: `if ( (1 || 2) != $current_user->ID )`. Perhaps a misplaced bracket, I am not sure. I am not well-versed in PHP so I'm sure this is a simple error.

```
if ( (1 || 2) != $current_user->ID ) {
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus_users');
}
```

If someone can help me out, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: you mean `$current_user->ID` should not be equal to 1 and 2. right?

Comment: You can't have "not equal to 1 or not equal to 2", for the reason I state in my answer - if it's 1, it will not be equal to 2, so will return true. If it's 2, it'll not be 1, so will return true. If it's 3, it won't be 1 or 2, so will be true. It's flawed logic that can't work.

Comment: I may be explaining it wrong. Basically, as long as the ID isn't 1 or 2 (two admins), I want the action to take effect for all other users.

Comment: In which case you want "If the ID isn't 1, AND the ID isn't 2", not or. Again, see my solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following corrections should solve your problem.

```
if ( 1 != $current_user->ID && 2 != $current_user->ID) {
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus_users');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shakti, you were the first one to answer and this worked so I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` comes down to `if ((true) != $current_user->ID )`. If you want to test one variable for multiple conditions, check it each time:

```
if (($current_user->ID == 1) || ($current_user->ID == 2)) ...
```

But you might want to look into roles. What if your site becomes very busy, and you want to assign another user admin rights but his ID is 872, are you going to hardcode this ID?

Comment: @cypher: User ID will not be in negative. Never. so this solution can work here because the input never be a negative number

Comment: @cypher true, but I'm assuming this is an unsigned int with a minimal value of 1, i.e. an identity.

Comment: @Shakti Depends on the system. You can't presume. Even basic database `int` fields allow for negative numbers, so it's a potential hole in the logic.

Comment: @Death: I am very much familiar with the system. It is WordPress and it does not implemented to have negative numbers for user ids

Comment: @ShaktiSingh, you can't presume a system from variable name. While it's perfectly likely that it is in this case, it's still a possibility it isn't. Could equally be custom code with a similar structure. Never deal in absolutes.

Comment: @Death: As I said I'm perfectly fine with WordPress and Even no CMS and OpenSource are implemented in the way, they accept negative integers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if($current_user->ID != 1 || $current_user->ID != 2){
     add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus_users');

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed. You can't have "if it isn't equal to a number, or it isn't equal to a different number", as it will always be not equal to one of them.

You should also reverse your order of comparison. Match variables to numbers, not numbers to variables. The following presumes you want to make sure the current user ID isn't equal to 1 or 2.

```
if ($current_user->ID!=1 && $current_user->ID!=2) {

}
```